# How to access data within nested span tags

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, request

I've tried replacing each string but I can't get it to work. I can get all the data between `<span>...</span>` but I can't if  is closed, how could I do it? I've tried replacing the text afterwards, but I am not able to do it. I am quite new to python.

I have also tried using `for x in soup.find_all('/span', class_ = "textLarge textWhite")` but that won't display anything.

**Relevant html:**

```
<div style="width:100%; display:inline-block; position:relative; text- 
align:center; border-top:thin solid #fff; background-image:linear- 
gradient(#333,#000);">
    <div style="width:100%; max-width:1400px; display:inline-block; 
position:relative; text-align:left; padding:20px 15px 20px 15px;">
        <a href="/manpower-fit-for-military-service.asp" title="Manpower 
Fit for Military Service ranked by country">
            <div class="smGraphContainer"><img class="noBorder" 
src="/imgs/graph.gif" alt="Small graph icon"></div>
        </a>
        <span class="textLarge textWhite"><span 
class="textBold">FIT-FOR-SERVICE:</span> 18,740,382</span>
    </div>
    <div class="blockSheen"></div>
</div>
```

**Relevant python code:**

```
for y in soup.find_all('span', class_ = "textBold"):
    print(y.text) #this gets FIT-FOR-SERVICE:
for x in soup.find_all('span', class_ = "textLarge textWhite"):
    print(x.text) #this gets FIT-FOR-SERVICE: 18,740,382 but i only want the number
```

**Expected result**: `"18,740,382"`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have two options here:

**1** - Use regex on the parent `span` tag to extract only digits.

**2** - Use `decompose()` function to remove the child `span` tag from the tree, and extract the text afterwards, like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

h = """<div style="width:100%; display:inline-block; position:relative; text-
align:center; border-top:thin solid #fff; background-image:linear-
gradient(#333,#000);">
    <div style="width:100%; max-width:1400px; display:inline-block;
position:relative; text-align:left; padding:20px 15px 20px 15px;">
        <a href="/manpower-fit-for-military-service.asp" title="Manpower
Fit for Military Service ranked by country">
            <div class="smGraphContainer"><img class="noBorder"
src="/imgs/graph.gif" alt="Small graph icon"></div>
        </a>
        <span class="textLarge textWhite"><span
class="textBold">FIT-FOR-SERVICE:</span> 18,740,382</span>
    </div>
    <div class="blockSheen"></div>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(h, "lxml")
soup.find('span', class_ = "textLarge textWhite").span.decompose()
res = soup.find('span', class_ = "textLarge textWhite").text.strip()

print(res)
#18,740,382
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could do it:

```
soup.find('span', {'class':'textLarge textWhite'}).find('span').extract()
output = soup.find('span', {'class':'textLarge textWhite'}).text.strip()
```

output:

> 18,740,382

Answer (score 0):

Instead of grabbing the text using `x.text` you can use `x.find_all(text=True, recursive=False)` which will give you all the top-level text (in a list of strings) for a node without going into the children. Here's an example using your data:

```py
for x in soup.find_all('span', class_ = "textLarge textWhite"):
    res = x.find_all(text=True, recursive=False)
    # join and strip the strings then print
    print(" ".join(map(str.strip, res)))

#outputs: '18,740,382'
```